# How to pass SQL Query client to server site through FireWall?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api

You can use the `DISTINCT` keyword with the `COUNT()` function in SQL Server to count the number of distinct values in a column of a table.

Here's the basic syntax:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column_name) 
FROM table_name;
```

This will return the count of the number of distinct values in the specified column.

For example, let's say we have a table called `Orders` with the following data:

| order_id | customer_name | order_total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Smith | 100 |
| 2 | Jane Doe | 150 |
| 3 | John Smith | 200 |
| 4 | Mary Johnson | 75 |
| 5 | Jane Doe | 125 |

If we want to count the number of distinct customers in the `Orders` table, we can use the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT customer_name) 
FROM orders;
```

This will return the count of the number of distinct customers, which is 3 in this case.

Note that the `DISTINCT` keyword is used to eliminate duplicate values in the column before counting them. If you omit the `DISTINCT` keyword, the `COUNT()` function will count all the values in the column, including duplicates.

I want to pass my SQL query on the server but firewall blocks me.
What to do for send my SQL query on server?

Comment: Do you have access to the firewall settings?